# jQuery Ajax call not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery Ajax call not working in Chrome Browser.

my code :-

```
function memories(pageName)
{
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: pageName,   
    success: function(html){
        $("#page").load(pageName); 

   }
 });    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but not passing in a URL. `load` is for loading content from a URL and then applying it to an element. You either want to use it without `ajax`, or you want [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

E.g., either:

```
function memories(pageName)
{
    $("#page").load(pageName);
}
```

or (more likely, as you've used POST, although as you haven't supplied any params it's not clear):

```
function memories(pageName)
{
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: pageName,   
    success: function(html){
        $("#page").html(html); 

   }
 });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `load()` where you should be using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the contents of an element:

```
function memories(pageName)
{
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: pageName,   
       success: function(html){
           $("#page").html(html); 
       }
   });    
}
```